# Network interfaces not enabled at boot

Tags: network-manager

I have an Ubuntu desktop install and I noticed that I can't communicate over any network interfaces until I actually log in and they are activated.

Is there any way to have NetworkManager activate all interfaces at boot time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't restrict the profiles to your user. Basically, clear `connection.permissions` property.

You can do that with various GUIs or

```
nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" connection.permissions ""
```

Note that your user needs certain PolicyKit permissions to be able to create systemwide profiles.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!